# Inserting commas into a block of text in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, csv

Right now I am working with a text file that happens to have all the data next to each other like in the following `string`: `AB005103012ES-**  OF**MID115748607.83`

However, I need to upload this to a `MYSQL` database, so ideally the translated format would have the code be separated with commas like so:

```
AB00,51,0301,2,ES-**,  ,O,F,**,M,I,D,1,157486,07.83
```

I am dealing with around 14 million lines and the commas would appear in the same character spot each time. As in the first comma would appear after the 4th character in each line, the second comma would appear after the 6th comma in each line and so on.

Is there any way to quickly achieve this in `MYSQL` or failing that, another simple program that could be run easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use INFILE along with the SUBSTR (substring) command.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

> To load a text file with fixed width columns, I used the form:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '<file name>' INTO TABLE <table>
(@var1)
SET Date=str_to_date(SUBSTR(@var1,3,10),'%m/%d/%Y'), 
Time=SUBSTR(@var1,14,8), 
WindVelocity=SUBSTR(@var1,26,5),
WindDirection=SUBSTR(@var1,33,3),
WindCompass=SUBSTR(@var1,38,3),
WindNorth=SUBSTR(@var1,43,6),
WindEast=SUBSTR(@var1,51,6),
WindSamples=SUBSTR(@var1,61,4);
```

Comment: In your example are those fields such as WindVelocity already defined as part of the table or part of a different table? And is @var1 the attribute for the first table?

Comment: Yes, those are columns of the table being imported into.  @var1 represents the given row being processed by INFILE.  You basically have to drop in your column names and appropriate SUBSTR commands to specify the range of characters to use within a given line for each column.

Answer (score 0):

i would run a simple macro in notepad++

Comment: well - assuming this was a one off...  if you need to repeat on future text files - maybe something more permanent

Comment: As far as I know this would have to be run on future text files, however the formatting should be the same in the future text files as well in that the commas will always be in the same place in each row. Would you mind elaborating more on this macro?

Comment: sure - in notepad++ you can say 'start recording' then insert the commas in the first row the way you like, then say 'stop recording' - from there you can run that 'macro' for every line of the file - it will zip to the end placing all the commas. - then just save and use as needed

Comment: That was my first thought too.  Notepad++ doesn't really like to run macros in files with 14m lines (very slow).